# Android:Quantity buttons in listview - only updates top quantity

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have created a list view with plus and minus buttons on each row but the value only changes on the top row also i need a way so that when i click submit order it will reference the type of coffee and say what the quantity is that that was ordered.

activity_main.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

customListAdapter.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
String[] description = {
        "Price: £1.75",
        "Price: £2.15",
        "Price: £2.80",
        "Price: £2.00",
        "Price: £2.80",
        "Price: £3.35",
        "Price: £3.15",
        "Price: £2.00",
        "Price: £2.45",
        "Price: £3.00",
        "Price: £2.25",
};

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}



public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText(description[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

myList.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Top text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#906B41"
        android:text="Bottom Text" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </View>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:onClick="decrement"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@layout/roundshapebtn"
        android:text="-" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/increment_button_view"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="increment"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="+"
        android:background="@layout/roundshapebtn"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Image showing the quantity only changes on the top value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7TnF.png)

Comment: this is becuase it may getting confused between `list item click` and `button click`... check for that

Comment: where are your onClickListener

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how is your on click listener code but i am providing some example for that-

```
 @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_custom_list_layout, null);
    } 

    //Handle TextView and display string from your list
    TextView listItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_string); 
    listItemText.setText(list.get(position)); 

    //Handle buttons and add onClickListeners
    Button deleteBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);
    Button addBtn = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.add_btn);
deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //do something
        list.remove(position); //or some other task
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        //do something
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});

return view; 
} 
}
```